# Unable to assign a value for my DateTime field inside a Remote event recevier. Error "Invalid date/time value"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, remote-event-receiver

I have the following code inside my remote event recevier, to assing a value for a Date Time field, as follow:-

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
  using (ClientContext context = Helpers.GetAppOnlyContext(siteUrl))
            {
          if (properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectApproveDelay"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectApproveDelay"].ToString().ToLower() == "yes" )
             {
               result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("ProjectEstimatedCompletionCurren0", DateTime.Now);         
             }
```

but this will return the following error:-

```
Invalid date/time value. A date/time field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again.
```

although both the server hosing the remove event receiver + the site collection follow the UK time standard. and the DateTime.Now will be something as follow `27/01/2020 23:01:32`

Comment: Im not sure, but try this code, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint, Date and Time Field takes date in ISO Format.

So, try converting date-time value in ISO format and then use it.

Try below solutions:

1. Converting to ISO Format:

   `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");`

   [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)
2. Try using Invariant Date Format:

   `DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);`

   [SharePoint: Assigning values to DateTime fields](https://gunnarpeipman.com/sharepoint-assigning-values-to-datetime-fields/).